# Create 75-Mins timeblock for multiple DateTimes of a day

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am working on a stock market software. Where I am having a candle every **5 minutes**. So whenever a time-frame of say 30 minutes is selected, what we do is -

```
long val = (long)(D * 24 * 60) / 30; //D is datetime of candle converted in OA date in double.
//The above code never create problem as (24*60)%30 == 0.
```

The above line returns same value for every half an hour chunk i. e. candle of 10:35, 10:40.....11:00. With that we can easily find out chunks of half an hour, whenever `val` is changed.

Now, We have a challange to implement the chunk of `75-Mins` in the same way. Our market start from 9:15 and ends at 3:30. Suppose date for which `75-Mins` needs to be calculated is `22-9-2018.` For that I will need to have exactly 5 candle of below time -

> 1. 22-9-2018 10:30 (9:15 to 10:30 = 75 mins)
> 2. 22-9-2018 11:45
> 3. 22-9-2018 1:00
> 4. 22-9-2018 2:15
> 5. 22-9-2018 3:30

I need to have same kind of code as metioned above which will calculate same value for these five chunks.

Problem I found is, If we start 75 from 12:00, then the chunk in market time will be at **8:45 to 10:00** while we require from **9:15 to 10:30** first chunk.

Also, (24*60)%75 = 15, So **15 Mins** difference everyday disturbs the next day calculation too.

**UPDATE -**

*To clear the question, For a chunk from 10:35 to 11:45, I will have candles like 10:35, 10:40, 10:45..... 11:45. For all these datetimes, I need a same numeric return value. As soon as the candle of 11:50 comes, the returned numeric value will get changed and my new 75 Min chunk will start. It will give same value till 1:00.*

Comment: You can declare a `DateTime` for a specific day and hour and use date related functions, `DateTime.AddMinutes` and `DateTime.ToOADate` withing a while loop.

Comment: @bradbury9 Not able to understand you clearly. Can u explain?

Comment: Check Reza's answer, it is what I suggested, using linq instead a `while` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop or a linq query like this:

```
var startTime = new DateTime(2018, 09, 22, 9, 15, 0);
var times = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => startTime.AddMinutes(x * 75)).ToList();
```

**Example**

Here is also another example about how to split a date range. In the following example, i included the start time also as part of the result:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> Split(DateTime start, DateTime end, int minutes)
{
    if (minutes <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $"'{nameof(minutes)}' should be greater than 0.",
            nameof(minutes));
    var result = start;
    while (result <= end)
    {
        yield return result;
        result = result.AddMinutes(minutes);
    }
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
var startTime = new DateTime(2018, 09, 22, 9, 15, 0);
var endTime = startTime.AddHours(7);
var times = Split(startTime, endTime, 75).ToList();
```

Comment: to comply with the 'we use OADates' you can `.AddMinutes(x * 75).ToOADate()`

Comment: Use the `Split` method.

Comment: You're checking for `(minutes == 0)` but report back `"should be greater than 1 minute"`. I'd rather suggest something like `"must not be zero"` to reflect the check. Also, other problems could arise with negative values and `end` being before `start`.

Comment: @Corak Yes I should check for `<=0` and the message `Greater than 0`, But the end before start doesn't have any problem, it returns an empty result. Thanks for the comment, though the validation is not the main point of the question. It's just there to show the OP they need some validation. In case of such obvious mistakes which dont have any conflict with author's idea, feel free to correct the code.

Comment: @RezaAghaei You answer helped me. Not exactly the way I wanted. But I was able to solve my problem. Thanks for that.